# How do you get the Angry Wings achievement in Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: achievements, jetpack-joyride

I've been trying so long to get this freaking achievement.

How is it done?

Answer (score 5):

I just got the Angry Wings achievement.
Here is what I did:

1. Pick these 2 gadgets: Free Ride & X-Ray Specs
2. Try to start the game with Profit Bird
3. Destroy it asap since the vehicle box will be quickly spawn
4. Use X-Ray Specs to get an early look on vehicle box
5. If other vehicle shows up, tried to avoid it
   This will give you an advantage to have different vehicle as the box will be quickly spawn.
   If you accidentally take the box, destroy the vehicle asap
6. If the Profit Bird shows up, take it & finally got the achievement

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

It all comes down to luck, unfortunately, there's no way to affect what vehicle you get.

The only strategy I can suggest is keep starting a new game until the first vehicle you get is the Profit Bird, destroy it and keep destroying every vehicle you get afterwards. Eventually you'll get the Bird again. I would suggest having a second chance stocked just in case.

The reason you should destroy vehicles as soon as you get them, is that the game seems to spawn vehicles only a little while after the last one has been destroyed, and you'll never get the same vehicle twice in a row. Since you're aiming for maximum vehicle variety, destroying vehicles as soon as possible is the way to go.

**Note**: This answer was posted before the availability of gadgets. In later versions of the games where gadgets are available, I would recommend equipping "Free Ride", starting games and dying until you start with the Profit Bird, then destroy it and keep collecting gadgets and destroying until you get another one, if you die, pause and restart the game rather than waiting for the score, this way you'll always start with a bird. This lowers the "luck" factor of this achievement significantly...

Comment: Yeah I kept going for the profit bird but when I died I hit restart and kept pauseing and i would restart until I got it again and when I did get it again it gave me the achievement was this a glitch I don't know or they did this purposely so I think restarts don't count as new games

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is very simple when following this steps:

1. Use Free Ride and X-Ray
2. Start a game with a ride, if the ride is not the Profit Bird lose the game and start again till you get the Profit Bird from the begin
3. Crush the Profit Bird ASAP and look for another one using x-ray
4. If you loose, pause the game quickly and press restart. Doing this you will always start with the Profit Bird.
5. Repeat this process till you find the second Profit Bird.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the same vehicle twice in a row. I did it with Mr Cuddles, but it wasn't in one game.If you're someone with the Romeo Alpha Delta achievement you might not have to destroy vehicles ASAP but for normal people you probably will

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna have to hope that the first vehicle you get is the Profit Bird. Then when you get it and any other vehicles, make them crash ASAP. If you live long enough, you'll eventually get the Profit Bird again. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use free ride and x-ray spec gadgets, unequip vehicle magnet and always start with profit bird for that make replay. Wait for luck sometimes two consecutive birds come then angry wings completed, I tried for 3 days and with no technique came success.

This is what I experienced and got angry wings.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the profit, pause the game and hit retry. When you get the profit bird again you will get the angry birds acheivement.

Comment: Does the next vehicle have to be the bird or can you just play until you get the bird again?

Answer (score 0):

I saved up for the Piggy Pack Jet Pack and set the options for Free Ride and Easy Dodge Missile Jammer.    Got the double Profit Bird twice in one session after weeks of trying.