# How can I get Angry Wings?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the Angry Wings achievement in Jetpack Joyride?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48360/how-do-you-get-the-angry-wings-achievement-in-jetpack-joyride)

There's an achievement called Angry Wings I just can't get:

> Get the Profit Bird Twice in One Game

I've gotten all the other achievements (except the new gadget ones) ages ago, but I've never managed to get the Profit Bird twice in one game yet. Is there any trick to it? Is there a set rotation of vehicles I need to keep track of to try and catch it twice in one game? Is it totally random?

I just got the X-ray specs so I can track which vehicle each power up contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its mostly relies on your luck :/

Try starting the game until first vehicle you get is Profit Bird,then just start destroying all the vehicles as fast as you can,if you survive long enough you will get it again.

You should destroy vehicles because when one is gone new starts to spawn and it is never the same as previous one.

Comment: The X-ray specs really helped too, as they let you know which Vehicle pickup to get.

Answer (score 2):

I just got the Angry Wings achievement.
Here is what I did:

1. Pick these 2 gadgets: Free Ride & X-Ray Specs
2. Try to start the game with Profit Bird
3. Destroy it asap since the vehicle box will be quickly spawn
4. Use X-Ray Specs to get an early look on vehicle box
5. If other vehicle shows up, try to avoid it.  This will give you an advantage to have different vehicle as the box will be quickly spawn.  If you accidentally take the box, destroy the vehicle asap.
6. If you get the Profit Bird, congratulations.

Good Luck!